# Como pegar localização do Usuário - Cidade Estado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar localização do usuário para que Eu possa fazer meu sistemas selecionar automaticamente a cidade do DropDownList Cidade.

Através de um blog o autor ensina como fazer este desenvolvimento que até tentei realiza-lo, mas estou tendo problemas com a biblioteca LookupService que não encontrei no Nuget do Visual Studio e assim não posso utilizar o using desta biblioteca.

**Linha que estou tendo problema**

```
LookupService servico = new LookupService(database);
```

Abaixo descrevo os procedimentos descrito pelo autor

Primeiramente devemos baixar um arquivo contendo base de dados de localizações já cadastradas [Arquivo com base de dados](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz)

Após isto usamos este código abaixo, cujo não consegui utiliza-lo por motivos acima descrito.

```
string database = Server.MapPath("~/Content/LocalizaUsuario/GeoLiteCity.dat");
            LookupService servico = new LookupService(database);
            Location localizacao = servico.getLocation(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
            if (localizacao != null)
            {
                Response.Write("Cidade: " + localizacao.city + "<br />");
                Response.Write("País: " + localizacao.countryName + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Código do País: " + localizacao.countryCode + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Região: " + localizacao.region + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Código da Área: " + localizacao.area_code + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Latitude: " + localizacao.latitude + "<br />");
                Response.Write("Longitudade: " + localizacao.longitude);
            }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que isto é ASP.NET MVC, se for está muito errado.. Isto parece ASP. em C#.

Comment: @Maniero como Eu disse peguei estas informações e estou tentando adapta-las no meu projeto o link de acesso ao tutorial é este. http://thiagomarcal.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/localizacao-de-usuario-obter-cidade-e.html

Comment: @Maniero caso tenha uma solução sucinta em relação a minha dúvida pode passar.